# how to hide and show specific text when click on it using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to make all subtitle invisible (or make a hint ) and when Clint click on the subtitle (or a hint) I want to show them the subtitle only that subtitle who have clicked to be shown

note: my list is from database locally

here is a picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOjQa.png)

and here is my code

```
body: FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        List snap = snapshot.data;

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text("error"),
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snap.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  " ${snap[index]['text']}",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  " ${snap[index]['answer']}",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              );
            });
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: you use any state management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the Stateful widget for maintaining the state.
- Declare a variable for maintaining the selected index.

```
  int? _selectedIndex;
```

- when you click list item then update the state as shown below snippet.

  - show subtitle conditionally `or` you can use `Visibility` widget.

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        List snap = snapshot.data;

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("error"),
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snap.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                " ${snap[index]['text']}",
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
              ),
              subtitle: _selectedIndex == index
                  ? Text(
                      " ${snap[index]['answer']}",
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    )
                  : null,
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: the code works but still one issue , when i scroll down and click on the subtitle it refresh and load data so i don't want to refresh and load data every time when click  how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a variable selected index. Show sub title only when selected index is equal to index

Comment: Didn't get it , your answer is so brief , please if that possible explain it with more details